# What topical anesthetics exist for the axillary area?

Tags: pain, topical-cream-gel

Oral topical anesthetics work great as first stage numbing before an injection of anesthetics during dentist procedures.

Are there similar topical anesthetics that could be used in other areas of the body, eg. the underarm when undergoing a sweat glans thermolysis procedure such as miraDry? (I know of cases when no topical anesthetics were used, leading to additional pain, and wondering if there's a reason for that.)